# Email server making TCP connections from source port TCP 25 to destination TCP 6666/66667

Tags: exchange-2010, filtering

I'm hoping you guys can help shed a bit of light of what's going on here.

I have recently set up some egress filtering rules to prevent unwanted egress connections on my network. In doing so I see some bizarre traffic that looks like there is traffic leaving my email server on TCP port 25 and is destined for TCP 6666/6667.

The connections have happened only 3 or 4 times in the last 11 days or so and it looks as though anywhere between 8 - 15 packets are sent and that's it. There seem to be no lasting connection between the IP's and I haven't be able to run a `netstat -ab` command while it's happening to try to find out what process is initiating the connection.

The server is tightly controlled, has Anti-Spam & Anti-virus running on it and is not used to browse the internet or anything like that. Windows patches are installed monthly and I don't see any behaviour that would indicate that the system is part of a botnet (no excessive MS Exchange queues).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what's going on or can shed a bit of light as to how I can uncover what's happening here? What I'm hoping is happening is that the foreign server is starting the communication on that port and the email server is simply responding to the request but I'm not sure that's the case. The firewall is a Mikrotik with RouterOS.

A log in the router looks like this

```
in:ether1 out:ether12, src-mac:00:0C:65:12:92:12, proto TCP(ACK,FIN) 172.16.0.10:25->205.211.XXX.XXX:6666 NAT(172.16.0.10:25->YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:25->205.211.XXX.XXX:6666 len 52
```

172.16.0.10 = private email server IP

205.211.XXX.XXX = destination IP

YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY = our public IP

Comment: Look at the rest of the packets.

Comment: You can't tell from a `FIN` whether this was an incoming or outgoing connection.

Comment: You need to find the logs of the `SYN` packets to see where it's being initiated.

Comment: My apologies - The first instance in the chain is a SYN,ACK

Comment: OK, but why can't we see it?

Comment: Honestly, I can't tell if this is an incoming connection or an outgoing one, but my guess is that it's an incoming connection to port 25, as would be expected for an email server.

Comment: I would like to clarify that this is very LIKELY a source port of 25.  I have been trying to find the answer to this myself as my firewall is also showing very occasional entries where the exchange servers have traffic going out as Port 25.  I have wondered if it is part of an existing connection and Exchange is somehow trying to achieve a two way link much like PASV FTP does, but so far have found nothing but the log entries.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an incoming request rather than an outgoing request.  It is unlikely the server would create an outgoing connection from port 25.

As the comments note, the FIN packet just indicates the connection is being closed.  It is possible the other server sent a message, or tried to send a message and did not wait for the response before closing the connection.  If the delay is long enough on your side, then the close can look to the router like a new conversation with invalid flags.

Your mail logs may show an incoming connection a few minutes before the times in your firewall logs.

Comment: I have downvoted this as I can actually prove this is an outgoing connection and it isn't just a random experience as others have it. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/b5201dbf-2171-4b74-8b47-a413b8652d49/exchange-using-source-port-25?forum=exchange2010

Comment: @netniV I've looked at the link you provided.  While it does seem to be common there is nothing to indicate that this is not a  connection being closed.  It is possible a server is connecting an not initiating traffic.   The connection should be closed no sooner than 5 minutes after the connection.  See section 4.5.3.2 of  https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt